# Inequality in triangle: $2\cos(A)\le\cos(B-C)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality

Let $ABC$ be an acute-angled triangle. If $A \geq B \geq C$, show that 
$$2 \cos(A) \leq \cos(B-C).$$

I've tried all sorts of trigonometric relationships to get this to a nicer form, but I couldn't arrive at anything manageable. I have observed that equality is acquired when $ABC$ is equilateral. Any tips?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $\pi > A\geq B\geq C > 0$ and $A+B+C=\pi$, we can know

1. $\cos(A) \leq \cos(B)$
2. $\cos(C) \geq \cos(2\pi/3) = 0.5$

So
$$
\cos(A) \leq \cos(B) \leq 2\cos(B)\cos(C) = \cos(B-C) + \cos(B+C) = \cos(B-C) - \cos(A)
$$

Thus
$$
2\cos(A) \leq \cos(B-C)
$$

Comment: Why is $\cos C\le 1/2$? You mean $\cos C\ge 1/2$.

Comment: @Chrystomath you are right, my typo.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B=\frac{\pi}{3}+x$, $C=\frac{\pi}{3}-y$, so $A=\frac{\pi}{3}+y-x$. Then the condition $A\ge B$ implies $y\ge2x$, that is $y-x\ge x$. Also $0\le y\le\pi/3$, so $$\sin x\sin y\le\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin(y-x)$$  Hence $$\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)\le\sqrt3\sin(y-x)$$ $$\therefore \cos(x-y)-\sqrt3\sin(y-x)\le\cos(x+y)$$ But this is just $$2\cos A\le\cos(B-C)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Using the Theorem of cosines and the additionformula we get
$$2\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\le \frac{(a^2+c^2-b^2)(b^2+a^2-c^2)}{4a^2bc}+\frac{4A^2}{a^2bc}$$
Now using that $$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$ and we obtain after simplifications:
$$1/2\,{\frac {2\,{a}^{4}-{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-{a}^{2}{c}^{2}-{b}^{4}+2\,{b}^{
2}{c}^{2}-{c}^{4}}{{a}^{2}bc}}
\geq 0$$

Comment: Thanks, but that does seem a little overkill; It would also be pretty hard to account for the $A \geq B \geq C$ condition.

Comment: Then give us a better proof!

Comment: Sorry, a factor $2$ was lost, and now the result Looks better!

Comment: That looks better, but why is that expression greater than zero?

Comment: Since $$A\geq B\geq C$$ then we get $$a\geq b\geq c$$

Comment: I know that; And thus we have $2a^4 \geq a^2b^2 + a^2c^2$ or $2a^4 \geq a^4 + b^4$, but in both cases the expression writes as something positive + something negative. Excuse me if this is trivial, but I do not get it.

Comment: It is $$a^4\geq b^4$$ and $$a^2\geq b^2$$ and $$a^2\geq c^2$$

Comment: Let me elaborate Dr. Graubner's comments. His final inequality can be rearranged as
\begin{align*}
a^2(a^2-b^2) + a^2(a^2 - c^2) - b^2(b^2 - c^2) + c^2(b^2 - c^2) \ge 0
\end{align*}
All terms except for $- b^2(b^2 - c^2)$ are positive. But
\begin{align*}
a^2(a^2 - c^2) \ge b^2(b^2 - c^2)
\end{align*}
since $a^2 \ge b^2 > 0$ and $a^2 - c^2 \ge b^2 - c^2 > 0$. I would like to see a slicker solution myself, if possible, and I'm approaching the problem from a pure angle inequality, rather than side-inequality, method.

Comment: Some words are lost?